# Polymer - Fire not updating the UI checkboxes

Tags: polymer

I have very simple setup. When I check on checkbox, a pop up will open and ask to link to another checkbox.

When I close the popup, whatever the checkbox I selected, both will be checked.

I have array updated with checkbox value.

After I close the popup, the values are showing right in the array but not in UI. When I select other tab and get back to this tab, checkboxes are showing right.

```
this.fire('details', this.details);
```

This is not working from child page.

How can I refresh the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

Above your `details` event, will fire an event with `on-<your-custom-event>` at parent element as `on-details` So you need to assign a listener something like at parent:

```
<child-element
     on-details = '_detailsChanged'>
</child-element>
...
Polymer {(

    _detailsChanged: function(e) {
        // e.detail will give you this.details object
      }
```

Or I assume you want to assign an object at the child and reflect observations on the parent, so at parent element :

```
<child-element
    details = "{{details}}"
><child-element>
```

and at the child element, you need to `notify=true` this object at property declarations and notifyPath with making observable changes at parent something like:

```
properties: {
      details: {
          type:Object,
          notify:true
      }
    }
..

this.set('details', nevDetailsValue);  //Use this.set method 
this.notifyPath('details');  // Than detail property will change value at parent.
```

EDIT : Need to specify the exact path !!

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/qQmoOx?editors=1011)

```
 this.notifyPath('details.<path which is changed>'); // ie:this.notifyPath('details.name')
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The solution you provided is not working. I think the issue is, changes are making in array in details and details object is not aware of those changes in array.

Comment: Which option you trying

Comment: I am trying second one

Comment: Please provide more details about error. As this is very common usage at Polymer. And there may need  a small adjustment. Objects or Arrays needs observable changes in order to reflect at parents. Here the link for more details

Comment: https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data

Comment: The issue I think is. that details have an array of objects which I am making changes to. That array object changes are not getting reflected.

Comment: details.person.push({
                name: 'John',
                id: '1234',
                isLinked: true
            }); While I am adding this to the existing details, record is showing up but john, 1234 and checkbox for islinked are not populating in UI

Comment: Ok. Please give the code how you do changes at detail property. Because the code top above has a syntax error. Also consider this.set('details', this.details) has no sense.

Comment: If you can see the new value at child element with console.log or what ever. You can observe at parent element with using : this.notifyPath ('details.person')

Comment: Check the link above I provided. Shows very detailed and clear info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183675/discussion-between-user3757426-and-hakanc).